# C : Problem with Jagged Arrays

Tags: c, jagged-arrays

I have the following code :

```
int *edges[500];
char arr[] = {'c','d'};
edges[0] = arr;
printf("%c - %c", edges[0][0],edges[0][1]);
```

What I want displayed is `c - d` but what is actually being displayed is `c -`
So as you can see above, the first element is being displayed but not the second one.

Why isn't the second element of the array not being displayed ?

Comment: Are you sure the `-` should be there?

Comment: @Jacob it ends up being there because `edges[0][0]` and `edges[0][1]` end up accessing uninitialized memory. On my computer, the program prints `c "`

Comment: Right, gotcha. But shouldn't the OP "want displayed", `c d` and not `c - d`?

Comment: sorry, the code was changed a bit from the ide to the question; i fixed it now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since an `int` and a `char` have different sizes, you should try `char *edges[500]`

Comment: Excellent; that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Type mismatch. `edges` is an array of 500 pointers to int and you are assigning a pointer to two characters to its first element.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the

```
t.c:6: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

message might have something to do with it.

In C, `'c'` is a (small) integer. You store those as `char`s in `arr`. However, by accessing `arr` as `edges[0]` which is an `int *`, you are actually retrieving (on most platforms) `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]` and `arr[3]` as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

`edges[0]` is interpreted as int array with elements {(int)'cd' , 0} (actually, the second element can contain any junk).

printf with specifier %c takes first byte of `edges[0][0]` (i.e. 'c') and first byte of `edges[0][1]` (which happened to be 0).

change type of `edges` to `char* edgeds[500]`.

Answer (score 2):

line 3

```
edges[0] = arr;
```

incompatible types in assignment: `arr` is a `char *` and `edges[0]` is a `int *`.

**What happens is this**:

```
int *edges[500];
char arr[] = {'c','d'};
```

arr[0] is 'c' and arr[1] is 'd'

```
edges[0] = arr;
```

Ignoring the type compatibility, edges[0] point to the `int` at the address where the 'c' and 'd' (and possibly two more unspecified characters) are.

```
printf("%c %c", edges[0][0],edges[0][1]);
```

edges[0][0] is the first integer in edges[0]: that's the mix of 'c', 'd' (and possible two more unspecified characters). That value is converted to unsigned char, yielding 'c' which gets printed.
edges[0][1] points to the integer right after the mix of 'c', 'd' (and possibly two more unspecified characters). That memory location has not been initialized and it may well be outside the range your process can access.

if you print an int instead of 2 chars

```
printf("%d\n", edges[0][0]);
```

you will see the mix of 'c', 'd' (and possibly two unspecified characters).

**Best thing to do is get your types right.**

Answer (score 0):

`edges` is an array of pointers to int. The expression `edges[0]` yields a pointer to int, not pointer to char. Treating it as a char array causes the wrong byte offset to be calculated, causing the value of an unexpected piece of memory to be displayed rather than the memory holding the char value 'd'.

Array offsets calculate the offset in bytes based on the size of the type pointed to:

```
foo_t * x;
ptrdiff_t difference = x[1] - x[0];
```

The value of `difference` will be `sizeof(foo_t)` bytes. `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, and `sizeof(int)` is typically 4, meaning that your code will dereference a value 4 bytes into the char array, not 1 byte into the char array.